# Windows command line/shell - While appending file to another file, how to ignore lines that match a regex?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm not familiar with Windows shell. So, let's say my file is like:

```
DontAppend this line shouldn't be appended
DontAppend this line shouldn't be either
Some lines
more lines
```

And I'm appending like this:

```
type file.txt >> AppendHere.txt
```

This appends the whole file. How do I make it so it skips lines that begin with "DontAppend"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command findstr will let you search for lines not containing a string or regular expression so you can use:

```
findstr /vrc:"^[^A-Za-z0-9]*DontAppend" file.txt >> AppendHere.txt
```

The /r option says it should use regular expressions and the caret (^) says it should begin with the string.

Edit: added a filter for non alphanumeric chars that **may** solve the Unicode issues (Unicode files sometimes have a non-printable indicator characters in the beginning).

Comment: +1 I have used Windows for years and never used `findstr` before after installing `unixutils` on every box ;o)

Comment: @didster I don't think I ever used it, but I have read about it somewhere in the past so I looked it up.
When you're a UNIX guy stuck in a Windows environment and not allowed to use unixutils/cygwin, you learn to find the parallels...

Comment: It works for all `DontAppend` lines except for when the file begins with `DontAppend`. Is there a regex for "beginning of file" to `||` them together?

Comment: I guess it's kind of a bug, that `^` doesn't match "beginning of file" as well. Luckily, `DontAppend` only ever appears at the beginning of a line, so I just removed the caret.

Comment: To clarify on my previous comment, it may be because my text files are in Unicode. The caret works for ANSI files.

Comment: ah, haha! That's pretty funny/creative. I tried `"^[^.]*DontAppend"`, and that works too. It's probably even safer that way.

Comment: You mean safer my way or the one you tried? The `"^[^.]*DontAppend"` **shouldn't** work actually since . is any character and negating it should match nothing, and not match the Unicode control characters.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, my mistake. Would you happen to know a way to strip those three Unicode BOM characters before sending it to `>> AppendHere.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Either get `grep` for windows or you could use Windows' own `find` command

```
type so.txt|find /v "DontAppend" >> output.txt
```

The `/v` option means output lines that dont match your string.

`find` works for very simple things like this but any more you will need a real filtering tool like `grep`