# Windows command line/shell - discarding the UTF-8 BOM

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

This question is in continuation to [another question about selectively appending lines from one file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838802/windows-command-line-shell-while-appending-file-to-another-file-how-to-ignore/12838974).

The regex that I'm using works just fine at matching the lines to keep/to discard. The problem is that the file was composed from a bunch of other files, and sometimes the line I want to keep started out as the first line of a UTF-8 encoded file. This means that the `findstr` command returns something like:

```
∩╗┐LineToKeep that started out as the first line in its file
LineToKeep another
LineToKeep more lines
∩╗┐LineToKeep that started out as the first line in its file
LineToKeep more
```

It's guaranteed that excepting the BOM bytes, the line will always begin with "LineToKeep". How can I get rid of those three UTF-8 BOM bytes, since these windows shell commands can't properly handle them?

I'm hoping for a way to remove them in place, or perhaps a modification to the `findstr` command from that previous question.

Since I know each line must begin with "LineToKeep" or "∩╗┐LineToKeep", I figure there's a way to compute something like `if (Line[3:10] == "LineToKeep") { Line = Line[3:]; }` for every line.

Comment: ..and this is why perl should ship with every OS ;-)

Comment: Have you thought about using Powershell instead of the vanilla command interpreter? Doing something like this would be trivial. The Windows shell doesn't like Unicode much.

Comment: I'm going to run the script in Visual Studio's pre/post-build events. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500320/post-build-event-execute-powershell, running a PowerShell script may be an option. It would feel kind of like an external solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up calling PowerShell in windows cmd:

```
powershell . "Get-ChildItem . | Select-String '^LineToKeep' | foreach {$_.Line}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative from [unix world](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file) that removes the BOM in file in-place:

```
sed -zbi "1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//" filepath
```

This requires to download sed 4.4 [for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe) from https://github.com/mbuilov/sed-windows which offers working [`-z` and `-b` options](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options-1) which prevent [corruption of line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652652/preserve-line-endings#comment82599963_11508669).